# How can I add content to my topnav bar, I want the user to be able to click on them and the information to pop up

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="#"<i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i> Search</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> Contact Us</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-about"></i> About</a>
    <div class="topnav-right">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Login</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to click one of these and the content shows below the navbar. I have tried researching this, but am unable to get the correct answer.

Comment: What do you want? Please try to explain better.

Comment: I have a top nav bar and i want to click the home page, or the about page and i want content to show up.. I want to know how to add content to the buttons

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the code in the snippet below, hopefully it answers your question.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
  <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
  <p>With in the code below pay attention to the data-target and data-toggle='collapse'</p>
  <p>If you implement them in your code you should be able to achieve the desired result<p/>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>
```